# Flash AS2 - For each loop returning odd order array

Tags: arrays, actionscript, actionscript-2, reverse

Here is my code

```
var inventory = new Array();
inventory[0] = "Potion";
inventory[1] = "Mana Potion";
inventory[2] = "Key";

for(s in inventory){
    trace(s);
}
```

But the trace returns 2, 1, 0. So then I try adding `inventory.reverse();` but with that I get 2, 0, 1. Why not 0, 1, 2? How can I fix this?

On another note, how can I relay these variables to textboxes based on the index?
I tried

```
for(s in inventory){
    "item" + s = inventory[s];
}
```

The text boxes on the stage have the variables of (item1, item2, item3, etc...)

but that doesn't work, any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate through the length, not the items:

```
for (var i=0; i < inventory.length; i++) {
    trace(i);
}
```

It's also less specific to add items to an array using `push()`, so you don't need to know beforehand how many items are already in it.

```
inventory.push("Potion");
inventory.push("Mana Potion");
inventory.push("Key");
```

Comment: Thank you, i was just using `=` to test out the array, but I'll keep `push` in mind. Any idea about the second problem?

Comment: @ThatBenderGuy For your second issue you want to be doing this: `this["item" + i].text = inventory[i];`